# How to format the search input to us format phone number

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

as in table the phone numbers are stored in us format as (###)-###-####

and i tried to search it, as im getting the input from user as string(phone number)

and i tried to convert that as

```
 search_input = search_input.unpack('A3A3A4').join('-').insert(0,'(').insert(4,')')
```

it works if the complete phone number is typed, but

as if the user input single digit , the query searches like %#--% like this and nothing

gets fetched , so how to modify that command

my query will look like

```
    result = users.where('users.phone_number_1 ilike :search', {search: "%#{search_input}%"})
```

or
on the above query is there any posiblity to remove the special charcter('(',')','-') while searching?, so that it searches with the phone number alone..

thanks in advance

Comment: _"phone numbers are stored in us format"_ – it's usually easier to store data without any formatting. This also makes it easier to search for phone numbers: just remove any non-digit from the search string and you're good to go. You can apply the formatting when actually displaying the phone number.

Comment: Yes, you can store data without any formatting, this is the best way. If your data is unformatted then you can show mobile numbers in any format if you want and do for this you will not update data. For the searching process, you will simply remove the extra characters and leave only the numbers and everything will work as you wanted (%123% too). On the Database recommended to always store data without formatting, formatting data must be written in the UI using mask technologies.